# What would be the SQL Select statement for mixed dates in one column?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, data-integrity

I have a customer who has legacy data stored in Oracle database. Such data contains mixed DATE values in one column in database (that field is VARCHAR(32)). 
For example they store '30-Sep-2009' and sometime '1254431689' (that is a timestamp in epoch time).

I have no option to split the data into multiple columns (so I have to deal with it).

Question is - How to convert the data on the fly in SQL Select statement?

Comment: Since you can't split the columns, can you convert the data in the undesired form to the other form?

Comment: Why not clean the data?  Write a quick script (Even in SQL...) to go through every row, detect if it is all numeric (and thus is epoch), or do the opposite, and replace the value with an acceptable standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case when instr(thecol, '-')=0 then "convert one way"
     else "convert the other way"
end
```

and the like, possibly with more `when` parts. Sad, really, and maybe worth encapsulating into a user-defined function to at least get it out of sight;-).